# DOMDocument::saveXML and LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG option

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm facing the problem with the `DOMDocument`'s `saveXML()` function.

When I call the `saveXML()` function on my Windows PHP 5.4.31 server, then the document is saved with expanded empty tags like when the `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` is present (but it is not).

What can I do when I do not want to expand the empty tags? Is there any default value I am missing, please?

Thanks